de @model ValidaBol.Models.Producto a @model IEnumerable<ValidaBol.Models.Producto> MVC net 8
tengo el siguiente Modelo:
public partial class Producto
{
    public int Sku { get; set; }

    public string? NombreProducto { get; set; }

    public string? NombreProvee { get; set; }

    public decimal? Precio { get; set; }
}

en la vista tengo lo siguiente:
@model ValidaBol.Models.Producto
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Buscar";
}
<h1>Verificar Mandante</h1>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="index" autocomplete="off">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="NombreProducto" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="NombreProducto" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Producto" />

                <span asp-validation-for="NombreProducto" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<hr />
@if (Model != null)
{
    **<div>
        <partial name="_GrillaProducto" />
    </div>**
}
else
{
    <div>
        <p>No Hay Datos</p>
    </div>
}

lo cual me envía a un DbContext, lo toma un Sp y me devuelve una Lista, que es en donde se me produce un problema; resulta que la consulta
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_Sel_Producto]
@NomProd varchar(255)
AS
Begin
  SELECT [Sku], [Nombre_Producto], [Nombre_Provee],[Precio]
  FROM [dbo].[Producto]
  Where [Nombre_Producto] like '%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@NomProd)) +'%'
  order by precio
End

me devuelve una serie de registros, que cumplen con la condición. hasta acá todo funciona como debería.
Pero al tratar de pasar los registros a la vista me envía el siguiente mensaje:
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ValidaBol.Models.Producto]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'ValidaBol.Models.Producto'.

la pregunta es cómo puedo hacer para que una vez que la consulta devuelva una cantidad uno o más registros, los pueda pasar a una vista que tiene una tabla, que es donde los quiero mostrar????
Gracias
acá dejo la vista parcial
@model IEnumerable<ValidaBol.Models.Producto>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombreProducto)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NombreProvee)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Precio)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
         @foreach (var item in Model) {
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreProducto)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NombreProvee)
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Precio)
                     </td>
                 </tr>
         }
    </tbody>
</table>

y este es la llamada al sp en el dbcontext :
      public List<Producto> BuscXProd(string NombreProducto)
      {
          List<Producto> Listprod = new List<Producto>();
    
          Listprod = Productos.FromSqlRaw($"SP_Sel_Producto
          {NombreProducto}").ToList();
          return Listprod;
      }

y esta es el método en el Controller:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Producto producto)
{
    List<Producto> ListProd = new List<Producto>();
    ListProd = _context.BuscXProd(producto.NombreProducto);
    return View(ListProd);
}

Todo el método de llamada y el método en el controller funcionan bien, devuelven los registros solicitados, pero al pasar los datos a la vista, se produce el error.
acá dejo el sp:
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[SP_Sel_Producto]
@NomProd varchar(255)
AS
Begin
  SELECT [Sku], [Nombre_Producto], [Nombre_Provee],[Precio]
  FROM [dbo].[Producto]
  Where [Nombre_Producto] like '%' +  LTRIM(RTRIM(@NomProd)) +'%'
  order by precio
End


@model List<ValidaBol.Models.Producto>  ????????????????

Lo que te quiso decir @Yussef es que tu vista recibe un objeto, no una lista.. simplemente decile que es una lista y no un objeto...

Gracias, pero al hacer esto en la vista maestra , me deja de reconocer el elemento :   public string? NombreProducto { get; set; }, que es el input por el cual hago la consulta

@RodrigoMenares muestra el código de la vista parcial, yo creo que ahí es donde te está tirando el error

ya, agregue la vta parcial, como ves no tiene gran ciencia

logre Solucionar la situación, tuve que recurrir a un formulario estándar , quitar el acceso al modelo, conservar eso si, el nombre de la variable NomProd,  y ahí se pudo dar el resultado deseado, Gracias

El problema es que tu necesitas envíar una lista de productos y asu vez que el modelo sea un solo Producto, para aprovechar los asp-for (supongo que para usar DataAnnotation, en caso contrario podrías usar un form puro de HTML y no tendrías el problema), esto es una "limitación" muy frecuente en el paradigma MVC, que es que tu modelo de datos no coincide con el modelo la Vista, y es que conceptualmente no tienen por qué coincidir.
En casos complejos, lo recomendable es crear un Modelo (una clase) especial para la vista, el cual debe contener los datos necesarios para formarla y a su vez contener los datos suficientes para general el modelo datos (tu clase Producto)
No obstante, tu caso no es complejo, por lo que creo es más conveniente usar ViewBag. El ViewBag te permite almacenar datos extras al modelo
Tu controller debería quedar asi:
public IActionResult Index(Producto producto)
{
   ViewBag.ListProd = _context.BuscXProd(producto.NombreProducto);
   return View();
}

Y luego llamas a la vista parcial de esta manera:
<partial name="_GrillaProducto" model="ViewBag.ListProd" />


Gracias, pero me produce una serie de errores : 1.- en el index me reclama que: @{
ViewData["Title"] = "Buscar";
}, no esta instanciado; el @if (Model != null)
{



}, no entra nunca pues Model esta null; y en la vista parcial Model, indica que es vacio,

@RodrigoMenares Algo tenemos que tener distinto, porque a mi me funciona perfecto: https://i.sstatic.net/6AvQ9QBM.png

saludos en la vista parcial, me reclama que Model no esta Instancado
